# How to generating IDs to preserve the relational integrity of multilevel XML while loading data using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, relational-database, primary-key

I am attempting to load xml files into sql server database using SSIS. My xml data structure is as follows:

```
<PRODUCT xmlns="http://www.areabc.com/ABC" version="5.252">
  <APPLICANTS seller id="0">
    <APPLICANT first_name="ABC" last_name="DEF" middle_name="" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.areabc.com/InternalUse">
      <INFO state="" country="" />
      <ADDRESS duration="10" description="">
      </ADDRESS>
    </APPLICANT>
  </APPLICANTS>
  .
  .
  .
  
</PRODUCT>
```

each XML file roughly gives me 20 tables (applicant table, info table, address table etc.) ((some XML files do not contains all the nodes)). I have 30 xml files to load. When I dump the data into SQL server tables, SSIS autogenerating table ID, like Applicant_ID, or INFO_ID, etc. Now this Applicant_ID or INFO_ID is same, like for Applicant_ID = 5 or INFO_ID= 8 for all 30 rows that is coming from 30 XML files. The same is with all the 20 tables (Image)

[image].

I am wondering how can I generate unique IDs for each table in SSIS so they can be joined and preserve the relational integrity. Example: Can join Applicant table with an address table.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual example for you.

You can adjust for your needs.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #city;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #state;

-- parent table
CREATE TABLE #state  (
   stateID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
   stateName VARCHAR(30), 
   abbr CHAR(2), 
   capital VARCHAR(30)
);
-- child table (1-to-many)
CREATE TABLE #city (
   cityID INT IDENTITY, 
   stateID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #state(stateID), 
   city VARCHAR(30), 
   [population] INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (cityID, stateID, city)
);
-- mapping table to preserve IDENTITY ids
DECLARE @idmapping TABLE (GeneratedID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NaturalID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<root>
   <state>
      <StateName>Florida</StateName>
      <Abbr>FL</Abbr>
      <Capital>Tallahassee</Capital>
      <cities>
         <city>
            <city>Miami</city>
            <population>470194</population>
         </city>
         <city>
            <city>Orlando</city>
            <population>285713</population>
         </city>
      </cities>
   </state>
   <state>
      <StateName>Texas</StateName>
      <Abbr>TX</Abbr>
      <Capital>Austin</Capital>
      <cities>
         <city>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <population>2100263</population>
         </city>
         <city>
            <city>Dallas</city>
            <population>5560892</population>
         </city>
      </cities>
   </state>
</root>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS 
(
    SELECT stateName   = p.value('(StateName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
           abbr         = p.value('(Abbr/text())[1]', 'CHAR(2)'),
           capital      = p.value('(Capital/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
    FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/state') AS t(p)
 )
 MERGE #state AS o
 USING rs ON 1 = 0
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(stateName, abbr, capital)  
       VALUES(rs.stateName, rs.Abbr, rs.Capital)
 OUTPUT inserted.stateID, rs.stateName 
   INTO @idmapping (GeneratedID, NaturalID);

;WITH Details AS 
(
    SELECT NaturalID   = p.value('(StateName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
           city         = c.value('(city/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
           [population]   = c.value('(population/text())[1]', 'INT')
    FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/state') AS A(p)   -- parent
      CROSS APPLY A.p.nodes('cities/city') AS B(c) -- child
) 
INSERT #city (stateID, city, [Population])
SELECT m.GeneratedID, d.city, d.[Population]
FROM   Details AS d
   INNER JOIN @idmapping AS m ON d.NaturalID = m.NaturalID;

-- test
SELECT * FROM #state;
SELECT * FROM @idmapping;
SELECT * FROM #city;
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. IMHO, whatever IDs generated by SSIS they are not useful, because they are not unique.

Comment: Like in the above example Applicant table has autogenerated applicant_id (5) (parent). in the child table( Info table) there are autogenerated Info_id (8). Info table also has applicant_Id (5). I am loading 30 files it gives me 30 rows with the same applicant_id (5). If applicant_id changes with each incoming file like (1,2,3 etc) then this will also reflect in the child table and can easily be joined. My question is how can I change this autogenerated ID to unique in SSIS. Thanks. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: **"...My question is how can I change this autogenerated ID to unique in SSIS..."** I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue! Using the same example as above, my data looks like this:

```
<PRODUCT xmlns="http://www.areabc.com/ABC" version="5.252">
  <APPLICANTS sequence id="0">
    <APPLICANT first_name="JANE" last_name="DOE">
      <INFO state="TX" />
      <ADDRESS duration="10" />
    </APPLICANT>
  </APPLICANTS>
  <APPLICANTS sequence id="2">
    <APPLICANT first_name="GARY" last_name="DOE">
      <INFO state="GA" />
      <ADDRESS duration="10" />
    </APPLICANT>
  </APPLICANTS>
  .
  .

</PRODUCT>
```

And when SSIS loads the data, it loads it as follows:

Applicants table:
0
1

Applicant table:
Jane Doe
Gary Doe

Info table:
TX
GA

So I have no way of knowing that Jane is from TX.  The SSIS load
assigns random _ID's but the ID's on the Applicant table don't match the _ID's on the Info table.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not an answer, please don't use answers to add comment like these.